# Angular 4 Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined error

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am using `.replace()` JS function in Angular 4 on one of the strings to strip few characters. In the component, I have written the code as below:

```
@Component({...})
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {
 routerUrl: string = '';

 constructor() {}

 ngOnInit() {
   this.routerUrl = "SOME_DYNAMICALLY_RETRIEVED_STRING";
   this.routerUrl = this.routeUrl.replace(/[`~!@#$%^&*()_|+\-=?;:'",.<>\{\}\[\]\\\/]/gi, '');
   console.log(this.routerUrl);
 }
```

but the code throws an error as

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
at SafeSubscriber._next ...
```

Please help me resolve this issue.

**Added Code**

```
export class CourseComponent implements OnInit {
routeUrl: string = '';

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2, private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
      this.routeUrl = params[':name'];
      this.routeUrl = this.routeUrl.replace(/[`~!@#$%^&*()_|+\-=?;:'",.<>\{\}\[\]\\\/]/gi, '');
      console.log(this.routeUrl);
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: `replace` doesn't work in situ (it doesn't mutate). You have to assign it. `this.routeUrl = this.routeUrl.replace(...)`

Comment: I suspect that error is coming from somewhere else in your code, given the `at SafeSubscriber._next` part of the error message. Or, the `SOME_DYNAMICALLY_RETRIEVED_STRING` is not set at the time the code is being executed. By the way, what is that regexp supposed to do?

Comment: @Kinduser Yes, but that would not account for the error he is getting.

Comment: @torazaburo Yeah, just a little hint from me :)

Comment: @torazaburo The regex just strips out all the characters I do not want, and just keep the alphabets, numbers and few characters.

Comment: What does the console log?

Comment: You should replace `this.routeUrl.replace` with `this.routerUrl.replace`.

Comment: @Kinduser here's the console log `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined`

Comment: Ekhm, I mean what does the console log from the `ngOnInit` function. Does it log anything?

Comment: @Kinduser The error throws before logging happens.

Comment: are you getting the string by `subscribing` to some thing?

Comment: @Aravind I am getting the string by subscribing to the route params. However I tried it outside that function, calling .replace() on a string. It still doesn't work.

Comment: Juste make sure that your variable has the same name in all places. You are using `routeUrl` and `routerUrl`, which are different.

Comment: @ConnorsFan yup.. I pointed that out in my answer.

Comment: @KyleRichardson routerUrl and routeUrl is just a spelling mistake in this post. But the spelling is fine in my original code and is properly defined.

Comment: @Proton Starlight I will delete my answer then. This is why it's important to post the actual code that you are having a problem with.

Answer (score 0):

If you are subscribing to some URL, place the replace inside the subscription as below

```
this.router.url.subscribe((routeparams){
   this.routerUrl = "SOME_DYNAMICALLY_RETRIEVED_STRING";
   if(this.routerUrl){
        this.routerUrl = 
         this.routeUrl.replace(/[`~!@#$%^&*()_|+\-=?;:'",.<>\{\}\[\]\\\/]/gi, '');

      }
})
```